# Make Share icons from Add This align  horizontally instead of vertically on self hosted WordPress

Tags: themes, wordpress

I have a problem that has taken me days to figure out.

The social follow icons I get from [AddThis](http://www.addthis.com/) website appear vertically instead of horizontally. I want to make it appear horizontally but I have found that it is impossible to do so.

Below is the code I got from https://www.addthis.com/get/follow

```
<!-- AddThis Follow BEGIN -->
<p>Follow Us</p>
<div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style">
<a class="addthis_button_facebook_follow" addthis:userid="TheMostafaAbedi"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_twitter_follow" addthis:userid="theMostafaAbedi"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_google_follow" addthis:userid="106914586115617584077"></a>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=xa-506a607f490b6601"></script>
<!-- AddThis Follow END -->
```

The specific page that the problem occurs is http://www.under-review.com/about under Mostafa Abedi description.

Answer (score 1):

You've got line breaks between lines of code, which makes the icons go one below the other. You're most likely using the WordPress editor to insert the code, which alters the formatting.

If you're using Visual editor, switch to HTML editor and give it a try.
If you're using HTML editor, at the very least remove all the spacing between items, making them placed in one line, which would prohibit WordPress from entering new lines, i.e.:

```
<a class="addthis_button_facebook_follow" addthis:userid="TheMostafaAbedi"></a><a class="addthis_button_twitter_follow" addthis:userid="theMostafaAbedi"></a><a class="addthis_button_google_follow" addthis:userid="106914586115617584077"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, about 90% of all formatting issues are fixed by good code and as a rule I follow W3C. I suggest you validate against that because at the moment it fails (both the HTML and CSS fails)

http://validator.w3.org/check?verbose=1&uri=http%3A%2F%2Funder-review.com%2Fabout%2F

http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?profile=css21&warning=0&uri=http%3A%2F%2Funder-review.com%2Fabout%2F